# How to store user input using prompt() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I were to have a prompt in my code like this:

```
prompt("What is your favorite animal?");
```

Is there a way to store the answer?

Comment: You can assign it to a variable. What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) You should read the docs: [Window.prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) There is even an example how to use this function.

Comment: Some friendly advice, these sorts of questions can usually be solved by a quick Google. Here is the first result from that https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp. The very first example shows an example of what you are looking for. People on Stackoverflow *really* don't like it when people come with questions that can be easily searched, since it wastes both your and our time.

Comment: I find it, however, nice to also share answers to basic questions on such a platform so if you're not really interested in reading some docs and want to remind yourself smth - you can specifically ask a question and get a fast and specific answer. If you feel like you're not familiar with the thing you're asking about - then you find resources like those mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign the function call to a variable and don't forget to perform answer checks

```js
var answer = prompt("What is your favorite animal?");
if (answer != null && answer.length !== 0) {
   // do your stuff here
   alert(answer);
}
```